# Replacing for loop with tensor multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, for-loop, matrix, keras, tensor

I want to do the following normalization in tensorflow, but I'm not sure how to.

I have a tensor `a`, which is of shape (c, c) and let's say c=16 in this case. I have another tensor of shape `b`, which is of shape (w, w, c) and w = 32, c=16 (so `b`'s dimensions are height w, width w, and depth/channels c). I'm ignoring the batch dimensions in both cases, but you can assume the `a` and `b` have the same batch dimensions/number of samples.

I would like to do something like the following, ideally using tensor notation/operations and not using this for loop:

```
for i in range(c): # loop over the channels
    y[:,:,i] = b[:,:,i]/(sum_j[a[j,i] * b[:,:,j]])
```

In other words, we're normalizing `b` by a weighted sum over j `a[j,i]*b[:,:,j]`, where j is indexing the channel. We do this for each channel i to produce `y[:,:,i]`. I would greatly appreciate help on how to do this using tensorflow functionality. Thanks!

Comment: are u able to provide a working example using numpy array ?

Comment: The question is how to **implement** this in tensorflow or if the procedure can be **optimized** by not using for loop? If the latter, then the best thing to do is, most possibly, looping in parallel for different channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let c = 2 and w = 3 for illustration.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.constant([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]], dtype=tf.float32)

b = tf.constant([
    [[11, 15],
     [4, 3],
     [3, 7]],
    [[22, 5],
     [15, 20],
     [1, 4]],
    [[16, 14],
     [3, 22],
     [2, 8]]], tf.float32)

a = a[:, None, None]
print(a.shape)
# (2, 1, 1, 2)

b_extended = tf.tile(b[None], [2, 1, 1, 1])
print(b_extended.shape)
# (2, 3, 3, 2)

norm = tf.math.reduce_sum(a * b_extended, -1)
norm = tf.transpose(norm, (1, 2, 0))

out = b / norm

print(out)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[[0.2682927  0.16129032]
#   [0.4        0.125     ]
#   [0.1764706  0.1891892 ]]
# 
#  [[0.6875     0.05813954]
#   [0.27272728 0.16      ]
#   [0.11111111 0.21052632]]
# 
#  [[0.36363637 0.13461539]
#   [0.06382979 0.22680412]
#   [0.11111111 0.21052632]]], shape=(3, 3, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Let's test with numpy and see if this is indeed what we want.

```py
import numpy as np


a = a.numpy()
b = b.numpy()

y = np.zeros((3, 3, 2))

for i in range(2):
    y[:, :, i] = b[:, :, i] / (a[i] * b).sum(-1)

np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(y, out.numpy())
# passes
```

#### Edit

You can just wrap it in a [`tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) and make your own layer and you'll need to account for batches now when you are expanding the inputs.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class CustomNormLayer(layers.Layer):
    """``CustomNormLayer``."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def call(self, x, y):
        # extract `c`
        c = tf.shape(x)[1]  
        # expand x
        x = x[:, :, None, None]
        # ----^ (batch)
        # tile y
        y_extended = tf.tile(y[:, None], (1, c, 1, 1, 1))
        # ---------------------^ (batch)
        # sum norm
        norm = tf.math.reduce_sum(x * y_extended, -1)
        # permute
        norm = tf.transpose(norm, (0, 2, 3, 1))
        return y / norm
```

Let's make a model and try it out

```py
a = tf.constant([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]], dtype=tf.float32)

b = tf.constant([
    [[11, 15],
     [4, 3],
     [3, 7]],
    [[22, 5],
     [15, 20],
     [1, 4]],
    [[16, 14],
     [3, 22],
     [2, 8]]], tf.float32)

# put data into a `tf.data` object
batch_size = 5
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((a, b))
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_iter = iter(dataset)

# define layers
xa = tf.keras.Input((2, 2))
xb = tf.keras.Input((3, 3, 2))
out = CustomNormLayer()(xa, xb)

# define model
model = tf.keras.Model([xa, xb], out)

# put some data in
data = next(train_iter)
model(data)[0]
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[[0.2682927 , 0.16129032],
#         [0.4       , 0.125     ],
#         [0.1764706 , 0.1891892 ]],
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. This was super helpful and I really appreciate your help. This is beyond the scope of the question so I completely understand if you can't help out further, but I am ultimately interested in using this to normalize layers in a cnn model (defined using tf.keras.layers). So `a` and `b` are the outputs of some layer in the model and I want to combine them (as specified above) to output y. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this for model layers instead of a constant tensor and would I need to tweak anything?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This has tremendously useful!